# Self-referential ReferenceProperty in Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I'm having a bit of trouble with ReferencePropertys in App Engine (Python).

For a bit of fun, I'm trying to model a folder/file system, but having trouble getting folders to reference folders.

My first attempt was this:

```
class Folder(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)
    folder = db.ReferenceProperty(Folder, collection_name="folders")
```

But that fails as "Folder" isn't defined when "folder" is trying to be defined.

I've also tried defining "folder" outside of the main declaration for "Folder", like so:

```
class Folder(db.Model):
    id = db.StringProperty()
    name = db.StringProperty()
    created = db.DateTimeProperty(auto_now_add=True)

Folder.folder = db.ReferenceProperty(Folder, collection_name="folders")
```

But that fails with:
    AttributeError: 'Folder' object has no attribute 'folders'

I'm kind of stumped. Does anyone have experience with this, or a  solution to this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That's exactly what [SelfReferenceProperty](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/typesandpropertyclasses.html#SelfReferenceProperty) is for.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a separate model to link the two, named something like FolderChild:

```
class FolderChild(db.Model):
    parent = db.ReferenceProperty(Folder)
    child = db.ReferenceProperty(Folder, collection_name="children")
```